# Jenkins: pipeline script - call plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing an Jenkins pipeline script and try to call a plugin what is in a normal job configuration configured under "build".

Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Pool+Plugin

I tried calling it via:

```
step([$class: 'ParameterPool', projects: '123', name: 'ID', values: '1, 2, 3, '])
```

But its not working.

Calling other plugins like:

```
step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', parsingRulesPath: '/opt/log_minimal_parser', useProjectRule: false])
```

works just fine.

How I can call a random plugin in pipeline script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot call any random plugin from a pipeline, instead you can only call plugins that have been made compatible with pipelines, which is the use of a newer API.

Your second plugin has been made compatible with pipeline, the first one just hasn't yet ! You can find a full list of compatible plugins here : [Plugin Compatibility with Pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md)

Comment: I was exactly looking for the list of `"Plugin Compatibility with Pipeline"`. Thank you!