# How to publish completed builds of a pipeline job to a public Jenkins instance?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a private Jenkins running on an internal private network not visible from the internet. I have also a public Jenkins instance, visible from the internet and accessible only over HTTPS.

How can I publish completed builds of a **scripted pipeline job** from private instance to the public one (including artifacts, logs, test results and so on)?

I know there's a [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin) for Jenkins, but I could not figure out how to use it from scripted pipeline.

**EDIT:** [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin) cannot be used from pipeline jobs without modifications. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632525/6309), you can only call plugins that have been made compatible with pipelines, which is the use of a newer API.

And since that [build-publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-publisher) plugin is not listed in the [`jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin COMPATIBILITY`[3](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) list, you would need to fork [`jenkinsci/build-publisher-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-publisher-plugin), and [make it compatible with the new pipeline interface](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/).

Comment: I know that but I was wondering whether there's any other way, not necessarily hacking & using this plugin in particular. In any case, thanks!

Comment: @J.V. I understand, and did not see another way beside hacking/patching.